# Is the usage of the article "a" correct?

Tags: grammar

> He is a pedant, a sesquipedalianist, an ambivert.

Is this grammatically correct? I am not sure about the use of "a sesquipedalianist".

Comment: That looks like a list, if it is part of a longer sentence then you should say so IN the question, not in dozens of comments. Include the longer sentence in your post because users read questions and answers. Authors shouldn't be clarifying or amplifying outside the actual question. Well, it's such a short question it could do with a bit more "meat".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"He is a pedant, sesquipedalianist, and an ambivert" can be rewritten more compactly as "He is a pedant, sesquipedalianist, and ambivert". You should group together items in a list that require the same indefinite article, and only use it once at the start.

Whether you use 'a' or 'an' at the beginning of a list to suit the first item, you do not need to insert the other indefinite article if one of the subsequent items would require it if written or spoken alone. He is an observer, optician, driver, and sculptor.

"Accrue: to come to one as a gain, addition, or increment."

American Heritage Dictionary (1992)
[Repeat indefinite articles](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/repeat-indefinite-article-use-a-strawberry-an-apple-or-a-cranberry.2528143/)

Comment: Is "He is a pedant, sesquipedalianist, and an ambivert", right?

Comment: It's right but you are allowed to omit the 'an' before 'ambivert'.

Comment: But it won't sound nice for "He is a pedant, sesquipedalianist, and an ambivert who is painstakingly ameliorating his knowledge of Computer Science." Secondly, can I use a comma before "and"?

Comment: If you think it doesn't "sound nice" that is your opinion. I think it sounds fine.  The comma before 'and' is called an Oxford (or Harvard, or serial) comma, which you can look up.

Comment: Yeah, but it's grammatically correct, right?

Comment: Is what grammatically correct?

Comment: "He is a pedant, sesquipedalianist, and an ambivert who is painstakingly ameliorating his knowledge of Computer Science." — This sentence.

Comment: In my second comment above I wrote "It's right". Don't you believe me?

Comment: It's right, but it's also grammatically correct if you leave out the 'an'.

Comment: I believe your reputation. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

These are the rules for a/an articles:

1. ***A*** before words starting with consonant sounds.
   e.g. A man, a university, a yacht...
2. ***An*** before words starting with vowel sounds.
   e.g. An animal, an error...

So the sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: I slightly edited the question. Is it right? Should it be "He is a pedant, a sesquipedalianist **and** an ambivert"?

Comment: @Cognoscenti Yes it's correct. And also "He is a pedant, sesquipedalianist, and an ambivert" or "He is a pedant, sesquipedalianist, an ambivert" are correct as well. You can take out two or more consecutive a's and make them single a. (But they have to be consecutive)

Comment: "You can take out two or more consecutive a's and make them single a." — How to take them out? Could you please write a sentence.

Comment: He is a fool, a bully, a horserider, and an optimist = he is a fool, bully, horserider, and optimist. Whether you use 'a' or 'an' at the beginning of a list to suit the first item, you do not need to insert the other indefinite article if one of the subsequent items would require it if written or spoken alone. "Accrue: to come to one as a gain, addition, or increment." - American Heritage Dictionary (1992) [Repeat indefinite articles](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/repeat-indefinite-article-use-a-strawberry-an-apple-or-a-cranberry.2528143/)

Comment: @Michael Harvey Okay, so it should be "He is a pedant, sesquipedalianist, and an ambivert", right? Should I also remove the " an" from "an ambivert" as you removed from "an optimist"?

Comment: If you remove the "a" before *sequipedalianist*, it sounds better if you also remove the "an" before *ambivert*. But you don't necessarily have to.